# Difficulty using BufferedImage in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bufferedimage

I have stored an image in a Resource folder 'Images':

> src
>
> -com.program
>
> -Images

In the program I use

```
BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myImage.png"));
```

to import the image.

This works fine. However, if i change the name of the image at the source(say to myImage1.png)
and try to execute

```
BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myImage1.png"));
```

I get Input==Null.
I've been try to get this to work for a while and tried various suggestions on other threads.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: what's the exact error msg/exception you get?

Comment: two things here. First is that you may have to refresh (right click the project, then refresh) the project after file renaming. Second is that the resource must be deployed with your class, because getResourceAsStream won't look for the file in the src dir, but in the bin dir (where compiled classes are)

Comment: The exact error is input == null

Comment: I refreshed it. Same problem. I changed the name in both the src dir and bin dir... Unfortunately, same error

Comment: Could you try clean and rebuild your project with _myImage1_ at a filename and in code?
BTW, do you use a build system (ant, maven, etc.) for your project?

Comment: I replaced (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myImage1.png")) with (new File("full-path/myImage1.png"))  .... It works. Thanks!!

Comment: But I don't understand why it didn't work the previous way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was most likely:

The image was in your `src` folder inside your project, but when the program runs, it runs from another folder containing your compiled classes. This folder did not contain the `png`, so you get the `input == null` exception (`getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` returns `null` when resources cannot be resolved).

To make it work, you need to mark the `images` folder a resource folder (using Eclipse, Maven or favorite build tool), and make sure that the contents of that folder is on your class path when the program is run.